# Doobie cannot find or construct a Read instance for type T

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-cats, doobie

I'm using doobie to query some data and everything works fine, like this:

```
case class Usuario(var documento: String, var nombre: String, var contrasena: String)

  def getUsuario(doc: String) =
     sql"""SELECT documento, nombre, contrasena FROM "Usuario" WHERE "documento" = $doc"""
      .query[Usuario]
      .option
      .transact(xa)
      .unsafeRunSync()
```

But if I declare a function with type restriction like this:

```
 def getOption[T](f: Fragment): Option[T] = {
    f.query[T]
     .option
     .transact(xa)
     .unsafeRunSync()
```

}

I got these errors:

```
Error:(42, 12) Cannot find or construct a Read instance for type:
  T
This can happen for a few reasons, but the most common case is that a data
member somewhere within this type doesn't have a Get instance in scope. Here are
some debugging hints:
- For Option types, ensure that a Read instance is in scope for the non-Option
  version.
- For types you expect to map to a single column ensure that a Get instance is
  in scope.
- For case classes, HLists, and shapeless records ensure that each element
  has a Read instance in scope.
- Lather, rinse, repeat, recursively until you find the problematic bit.
You can check that an instance exists for Read in the REPL or in your code:
  scala> Read[Foo]
and similarly with Get:
  scala> Get[Foo]
And find the missing instance and construct it as needed. Refer to Chapter 12
of the book of doobie for more information.
    f.query[T].option.transact(xa).unsafeRunSync()

Error:(42, 12) not enough arguments for method query: (implicit evidence$1: doobie.util.Read[T], implicit h: doobie.LogHandler)doobie.Query0[T].
Unspecified value parameter evidence$1.
    f.query[T].option.transact(xa).unsafeRunSync()
```

Does anyone know how to make what I want? I think it's something with implicits but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order for *doobie* to be able to transform the result of SQL query to your case class, it needs an instance of `Read` *typeclass* in scope.

For example for `Usuario` it needs instance of `Read[Usuario]`. Fortunately, *doobie* is able to derive *typeclasses* for types from *typeclasses* it already knows, like `String`, so in most cases, we don't need to create these explicitly.

In your case, you want to create method `getOption` which has type parameter `T`, which means, that compiler doesn't know for which *typeclass* of which type to look for.

You can fix it very easily, by just adding context-bound for `Read` to your type (like `T: Read` or by adding implicit parameter). It means that your method will pass *"request"* to resolve *typeclass* later in compile-time when the concrete type of T would be already known.

So your fixed method will be:

```
def getOption[T: Read](f: Fragment): Option[T] = {
    f.query[T]
     .option
     .transact(xa)
     .unsafeRunSync()
```

or with implicit parameter:

```
def getOption[T](f: Fragment)(implicit read: Read[T]): Option[T] = {
    f.query[T]
     .option
     .transact(xa)
     .unsafeRunSync()
```

Comment: I often times will receive this error when I provide the wrong type to "query[T]"