# circe automatic parse json to case class, but some key value is missing

Tags: scala, circe

my json file look like

```
{
 "product1" : {
               "data1" : [0, 0, 0, ...],
               "data2" : [0, 0, 0, ...]
              },
 "product2" : {
               "data1" : [0, 0, 0, ...],
               "data2" : [0, 0, 0, ...]
              }
 ...
}
```

my case class is

```
case class Product(code: String, detail: Detail)
case class Detail(data1: List[Int], data2: List[Int])
```

[modify question for certainty]

but circe fail parse

```
decode[Product](MyJson)
```

return fail (Letf).

is there more suitable case class? or

may circe can derive Decoder from mapping Map[String, Detail] ?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58530983/doobie-cannot-find-or-construct-a-read-instance-for-type-t) solve your problem?

Comment: In the title, you mention **circe** but the question is about **doobie**, I don't understand.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I believe author uses Postgres with `jsonb` type and want to use Doobie's Postgres extensions for JSON with Circe support. But it's a guess.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez sorry for causing confusion. I modify question for more specificly.

Comment: @FreyrVanAesir well your JSON has multiple products, so maybe you want to decode it to a `List[Product]`? Second, you would need to create a custom `Decoder` since your format and your case class don't match.