# Doobie cannot find or construct a Read instance for Type of case class with Timestamp

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-cats, doobie

Given a case class representation of a data row with a `java.sql.Timestamp`:

```
 case class ExampleRow(id: String, ts: Timestamp)
```

And query expecting an `ExampleRow`:

```
 import doobie._
 import doobie.implicits._
 import doobie.postgres.implicits._

 val queryExampleRows = 
   sql"select * from example".query[ExampleRow].to[List]
```

There is a resulting compile error:

> Cannot find or construct a Read instance for type:
>
> ExampleRow

This is surprising given that [the documentation](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/12-Custom-Mappings.html) claims that Timestamp should work.  Further, I know that the Timestamp is the cause because removing that member results in the code compiling.

**How can a case class contain a Timestamp and capable of being queried by doobie?**

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58530983/doobie-cannot-find-or-construct-a-read-instance-for-type-t#:%7E:text=You%20can%20fix%20it%20very,T%20would%20be%20already%20known.) but I cannot figure out if it applicable to my question since it involves a type parameter `T` and not a concrete type like Timestamp.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Try `import doobie.implicits.javasql._`

Comment: Isn't `java.sql.Timestamp` a deprecated class that should not be used for years? Use `java.time` whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the suggestion from the comments the problem was solved by transitioning the type from `java.sql.Timestamp` to `java.time.Instant`.